# How to reference anonymous inner class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have following extension method. How can I reference the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` that is passed into the `addOnGLobalLayoutListener()` method? I need to pass the listener to the `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener()` method.

```
fun View.OnGlobalLayout(callback:() -> Unit ): Unit{
    this.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            this.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
        else {
            this.viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074356/kotlin-recommended-way-of-unregistering-a-listener-with-a-sam

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) instead of [lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) like so:

```
fun View.OnGlobalLayout(callback: () -> Unit): Unit {
    val viewTreeObserver = this.viewTreeObserver
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
            callback();
        }
    })
}
```